# How to replace text using regex with back-referece in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm converting Windows batch script .bat to Linux batch script .sh

What takes time a lot is to change the way .bat script use variables.

i.e.

In Windows

```
@set varName=122
echo %varName%
```

In Linux

```
varName=122
echo $varName
```

So the question is, how to replace `%.+%` to `$.+` ?

Comment: You should accept your own answer if you don't expect there to be another better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), use the following:

Find what: `%(.+)%`
Replace with: `$\1`
Search Mode: Regular expression

[image: screen shot of replace dialog]